# Are font sizes only global in Notepad ++?

Tags: notepad++

It seems that the only way to change font size is by doing the global setting.  I cannot change the size of individual words.

Comment: Notepad is a plain text editor, it doesn't support formatting like Word or Libre Office

Answer (score 1):

This is possible for certain list of words, e.g. all strings, all comments, etc.

Open Settings → Style Configurator, and for Global Styles, make sure *Enable Global Font Size* is not checked

In the Language and Style lists on the left, select the language and style of word for which you want to change the font size. Select a font size on the right.

Here's an example for an HTML file with a larger font for attribute 'words':

[image: Example with large attributes]